# Can't delete JavaScript tag from HTML Page in VS 2012(Strange)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have write some javascript code in my html page, But i cant delete the code.

See the below image 
[image]

There is de-expandable code, But i can't clear the code.I think it's a visual studio bug.

**When i close and reopen the page, then it's gone.  But i want to know why it's happen?**

Comment: try closing and reopening visual studio

Comment: I know the solution, But i want to know why it's happen?

Comment: Is there any javascript debugger attached to VS instance?